# Is there any website which offers C++ IDE to run the codes in the cloud?

Tags: c++, cloud

Is there any website which offers C++ IDE to run the codes in the cloud? Something like [this](http://www.monkeyanalytics.com/) which is for Python and matlab (octave in fact);

Comment: Codiad++ is the one I use http://couleetechlink.com/new2/codiad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are seeking. You speak about simply Running C++, like JSFiddle but for C++, but then you mention IDE implying more features than the basic "Run this code in the browser" options.

At any rate, [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) is a full suited "Cloud IDE", which can handle any language you want. It's basically an Ubuntu computer in the cloud, with full root. This may be more extreme than you want, i'm not sure, let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: I checked Koding.com. It is not IDE but still it is the closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: You can write in vim although vim cannot be count as an IDE.

Answer (score 3):

This one is nice for short snippets : http://codepad.org/
Or this one : http://ideone.com/

There is a lot of other websites proposing online compilers on google : http://www.google.com/search?q=online+c%2B%2B+compiler&hl=en&ei=2whaTJaUPIb20wTL1_3jCA&start=10&sa=N

Comment: The problem of this website is that if the outputs are not in the standard I/O, it doesn't show them.

Comment: I just tried using std::cout and it work nice. That said it can't use input, yes.

I remember another website I'm searching now. It was a C++ project ide free and online, but limited in source files space. If I can find it it would be a good answer for you.

Comment: Thank you but I mean if you write the outputs in a file, this website (codepad.org) doesn't show them.

Comment: Right, but it's hard to get a file from this kind of website anyway. You can say it's not really "the cloud"... 
I'm searching for this website, I think  it was http://www.codeide.com/ but it seems offline now... http://www.codeide.com/

Comment: Anyway, maybe it's a good day to make a new cloud web app that let you do this exactly like you meant!